# HttpModule fires several times

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 with an HttpModule. I am aware that module's Init method may be called several times, once for each HttpApplication object, but I expect the actual BeginRequest event to fire only ONCE for each incoming web request. That's not what's happening.

I noticed that BeginRequest consistently fires twice for a simple POST I am sending to the server. I am sure I am sending only one request -- there are no images.

Why would BeginRequest be called multiple times for a simple POST to the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - IHttpModule.BeginRequest firing 2X, Application\_BeginRequest firing 1X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181648/asp-net-ihttpmodule-beginrequest-firing-2x-application-beginrequest-firing-1x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fire on every request, it may be images, scripts, handlers, pages, what ever.

If you debug and step on it you can see what files calls it. You can also place this line inside to see what is calling it live.

```
Debug.Write("call from: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);
```

Comment: Ah yes. I see it now -- it was a call to a WCF service to Grid.svc/Execute. The first call is to this exact URL, the second call is to Grid.svc, so my guess is that WCF runtime stripped Execute as a method name and now is calling Execute on the service bound to Grid.svc. Thanks for your help.